# Java - sending HTTP parameters via POST method easily

Tags: java, http, post, http-post, httpurlconnection

I am successfully using this code to send  `HTTP` requests with some parameters via `GET` method:

```java
void sendRequest(String request) {
    // i.e.: request = "http://example.com/index.php?param1=a&param2=b&param3=c";
    URL url = new URL(request);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
    connection.connect();
}
```

Now, I may need to send the parameters (i.e. param1, param2, param3) via `POST` method because they are very long.
I was thinking to add an extra parameter to that method (i.e. String httpMethod).

How can I change the code above as little as possible to be able to send paramters either via `GET` or `POST`?

I was hoping that changing

```
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

to

```
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

would have done the trick, but the parameters are still sent via GET method.

Has `HttpURLConnection` got any method that would help?
Is there any helpful Java construct?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Post parameters are sent inside the http header section not in the URL. (your post url would be `http://example.com/index.php`)

Comment: there is no method setRequestMethod in Java 1.6 defined: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html

Comment: Cast it to Http(s)UrlConnection ....

Comment: extending the question! Does anyone has any clue how to send an attachment as post parameter ...

Answer (score 499, accepted):

In a GET request, the parameters are sent as part of the URL.

In a POST request, the parameters are sent as a body of the request, after the headers.

To do a POST with HttpURLConnection, you need to write the parameters to the connection after you have opened the connection.

This code should get you started:

```
String urlParameters  = "param1=a&param2=b&param3=c";
byte[] postData       = urlParameters.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
int    postDataLength = postData.length;
String request        = "http://example.com/index.php";
URL    url            = new URL( request );
HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
conn.setDoOutput( true );
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
conn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
conn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
conn.setUseCaches( false );
try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream())) {
   wr.write( postData );
}
```

Comment: Hi Alan. In your code there is no call to connect(). Is that right?

Comment: That's right, `url.openConnection()` opens the connection for us already, so we just need to write to it.

Comment: +1 to this answer since it actually answers the OP's question, my answer deflects somewhat :-)

Comment: @Alan Geleynse : 'url.openconnection()' does not open connection. In case you do not specify a connect() statement the connection is opened when you write to to the http request body /heared and send it. I have tried this with certificates. The ssl handshake takes place only after you call connect or when you send a data to the server.

Comment: getBytes() uses default charaset of environment, NOT UTF-8
charset=utf-8 must follw the content type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8
You do byte conversion twice in the example. Should do:
byte[] data = urlParameters.getData("UTF-8");
connection.getOutputStream().write(data);

no use to close AND flush AND disconnect

Comment: If you are sending very large amounts of data, you might also call      connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(dataLength), as this enables streaming directly to the server, without buffering the data locally in memory.

Comment: Can I add "body" to this request?

Comment: Will the connection be established even though no response data is retrieved? I understand that unless you get the input stream or the response, no connection will be made.

Comment: @PeterKriens Thanks for your addition -- I believe you meant `byte[] data = urlParameters.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))` :).

Comment: When writing a String into the response body, it's probably cleaner to use `OutputStreamWriter` (which is specifically for writing *character streams*), instead of `DataOutputStream`, as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13468601/56285).

Comment: @AlanGeleynse Don't you miss wr.flush(); and wr.close(); at the end?

Comment: no need to call `cox.setDoInput ( true );` - the default is true.

Comment: conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); for retrieving json

Comment: I need to send a https request. Do this method support? If yes any modifications on configuration have to be done?

Comment: I am not sure how old this post is, but I have some questions.

1) The way i did it was put the para inside the url, i am guessing this means the paras are exposed evne when using POST?

2) correct me if im wrong, you openConnection(), which connects? links? to page via post, but then the actually post data is sent after it connects, and so post data is NOT exposed ?

Comment: @confile As I understanding, when we use "try with resources" with Closeable classes, closing of stream going automatically. It should work for Flushable too.

Comment: Can same be achieved using `org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient`?

Comment: try-with-resources just implements an auto Closeable with handling for null if the constructor threw an Exception during instantiation. Should not have 'fixed' any code otherwise. Also look at StandardCharsets class for UTF8 et al ... no need to hard-code String literals (bad practice).

Comment: How come this has so many upvotes, if it is not working? You need to call either `conn.getResponseCode()` or `conn.getInputStream()` otherwise it will not send any data.

Comment: Can you help with the reference where it explains what each line does here?

Comment: @ImaskarsaysReinstateMonica **conn.getResponseCode()** is not part of the sending post pack, specifically

Comment: Well, for me it solved the problem and without it the code wasn't working.

Answer (score 258):

Here is a simple example that submits a form then dumps the result page to `System.out`. Change the URL and the POST params as appropriate, of course:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("http://example.net/new-message.php");
        Map<String,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        params.put("name", "Freddie the Fish");
        params.put("email", "fishie@seamail.example.com");
        params.put("reply_to_thread", 10394);
        params.put("message", "Shark attacks in Botany Bay have gotten out of control. We need more defensive dolphins to protect the schools here, but Mayor Porpoise is too busy stuffing his snout with lobsters. He's so shellfish.");

        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
            if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            postData.append('=');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
        }
        byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

        Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

        for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;)
            System.out.print((char)c);
    }
}
```

---

If you want the result as a `String` instead of directly printed out do:

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;)
            sb.append((char)c);
        String response = sb.toString();
```

Comment: This is the best answer as it includes parameter encoding and use of Map.

Comment: Unfortunately this code assumes that the encoding of the content is  `UTF-8`, which is not always the case. To retrieve the charset, one should get the header `Content-Type` and parse the charset of that. When that header is not available, use the standard http one: `ISO-8859-1`.

Comment: @Aprel IFTFY... using expressions with side effects in evaluations is ugly indeed.

Comment: @engineercoding Unfortunately for HTML it's even harder than that to do it completely correctly, as there could also be a Unicode BOM, or a `<meta charset="...">` or `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="...">` header inside the document that needs to be parsed.

Comment: and for reading in a string .use String line,response;
                  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                          conn.getInputStream()));
                  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                      response += line;
                  }

Comment: @Nepster Don't do that. `response += line;` is phenomenally slow, and it eats line breaks. I've added to the answer an example of getting a string response.

Comment: tried , this prints  """A servlet request to the URI http://localhost:8089/********** contains form parameters in the request body but the request body has been consumed by the servlet or a servlet filter accessing the request parameters. Only resource methods using @FormParam will work as expected. Resource methods consuming the request body by other means will not work as expected. """

Comment: do we need to perform  conn.getOutputStream().flush()

Answer (score 66):

I couldn't get [Alan's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4206094/662581) to actually do the post, so I ended up with this:

```
String urlParameters = "param1=a&param2=b&param3=c";
URL url = new URL("http://example.com/index.php");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

conn.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

writer.write(urlParameters);
writer.flush();

String line;
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
writer.close();
reader.close();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this code doesn't read the response. It reads the empty form html.

Comment: what i had to add to alan's example was opening response stream. before i had done it, no bytes were actually sent.

Comment: Removing the writer.close() call did it for me.

Answer (score 25):

I find `HttpURLConnection` really cumbersome to use. And you have to write a lot of boilerplate, error prone code. I needed a lightweight wrapper for my Android projects and came out with a library which you can use as well: **[DavidWebb](http://hgoebl.github.io/DavidWebb/)**.

The above example could be written like this:

```
Webb webb = Webb.create();
webb.post("http://example.com/index.php")
        .param("param1", "a")
        .param("param2", "b")
        .param("param3", "c")
        .ensureSuccess()
        .asVoid();
```

You can find a list of alternative libraries on the link provided.

Comment: I'm not going to upvote because your post was less of an answer and more of an advert... but, I played with your library and I like it. Very succinct; lots of syntactical sugar; if you use Java as a bit of a scripting language as I do then it's a great library for very quickly and efficiently adding some http interactions.  Zero boilerplate is valuable at times and it may have been useful to the OP.

Comment: I'll upvote. I've succesfully used DavidWebb in one of my apps, and will do so for two more I'll be developing soon. Very easy to use.

Comment: Thank you, using DefaultHttpClient with https on Android fails with SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate (even on correctly signed https certificates), using URL is cumbersome (encoding parameters, checking for result). Using DavidWebb worked for me, thanks.

Comment: no AsyncTask support? So locking the UI thread by default...that's bad

Comment: It's a very basic library. The programmer has to call it from background-thread, in AsyncTask, in IntentService, in Synchronization Handler and the like. And it doesn't depend on Android -> can be used in Java SE and EE as well.

Answer (score 14):

```
import java.net.*;

public class Demo{

  public static void main(){

       String data = "data=Hello+World!";
       URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8084/WebListenerServer/webListener");
       HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
       con.setRequestMethod("POST");
       con.setDoOutput(true);
       con.getOutputStream().write(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
       con.getInputStream();

    }

}
```

Comment: WTH `import java.net.*;`!

Answer (score 12):

i have read above answers and have created a utility class to simplify HTTP request. i hope it will help you.

**Method Call**

```
  // send params with Hash Map
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("email","me@example.com");
    params.put("password","12345");

    //server url
    String url = "http://www.example.com";

    // static class "HttpUtility" with static method "newRequest(url,method,callback)"
    HttpUtility.newRequest(url,HttpUtility.METHOD_POST,params, new HttpUtility.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void OnSuccess(String response) {
        // on success
           System.out.println("Server OnSuccess response="+response);
        }
        @Override
        public void OnError(int status_code, String message) {
        // on error
              System.out.println("Server OnError status_code="+status_code+" message="+message);
        }
    });
```

**Utility Class**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import static java.net.HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK;

public class HttpUtility {

 public static final int METHOD_GET = 0; // METHOD GET
 public static final int METHOD_POST = 1; // METHOD POST

 // Callback interface
 public interface Callback {
  // abstract methods
  public void OnSuccess(String response);
  public void OnError(int status_code, String message);
 }
 // static method
 public static void newRequest(String web_url, int method, HashMap < String, String > params, Callback callback) {

  // thread for handling async task
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
    try {
     String url = web_url;
     // write GET params,append with url
     if (method == METHOD_GET && params != null) {
      for (Map.Entry < String, String > item: params.entrySet()) {
       String key = URLEncoder.encode(item.getKey(), "UTF-8");
       String value = URLEncoder.encode(item.getValue(), "UTF-8");
       if (!url.contains("?")) {
        url += "?" + key + "=" + value;
       } else {
        url += "&" + key + "=" + value;
       }
      }
     }

     HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
     urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
     urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); // handle url encoded form data
     urlConnection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
     if (method == METHOD_GET) {
      urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
     } else if (method == METHOD_POST) {
      urlConnection.setDoOutput(true); // write POST params
      urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
     }

     //write POST data 
     if (method == METHOD_POST && params != null) {
      StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
      for (Map.Entry < String, String > item: params.entrySet()) {
       if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
       postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(item.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
       postData.append('=');
       postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(item.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
      }
      byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
      urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
      urlConnection.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

     }
     // server response code
     int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
     if (responseCode == HTTP_OK && callback != null) {
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
      StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
      String line;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       response.append(line);
      }
      // callback success
      callback.OnSuccess(response.toString());
      reader.close(); // close BufferReader
     } else if (callback != null) {
      // callback error
      callback.OnError(responseCode, urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
     }

     urlConnection.disconnect(); // disconnect connection
    } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     if (callback != null) {
      // callback error
      callback.OnError(500, e.getLocalizedMessage());
     }
    }
   }
  }).start(); // start thread
 }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I see some other answers have given the alternative, I personally think that intuitively you're doing the right thing ;).  Sorry, at devoxx where several speakers have been ranting about this sort of thing.

That's why I personally use Apache's HTTPClient/[HttpCore](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-dev/index.html) libraries to do this sort of work, I find their API to be easier to use than Java's native HTTP support.  YMMV of course!

Answer (score 6):

GET and POST method set like this... Two types for api calling 1)get() and 2) post() . get() method to get value from api json array to get value & post() method use in our data post in url and get response.

```
 public class HttpClientForExample {

    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        HttpClientExample http = new HttpClientExample();

        System.out.println("Testing 1 - Send Http GET request");
        http.sendGet();

        System.out.println("\nTesting 2 - Send Http POST request");
        http.sendPost();

    }

    // HTTP GET request
    private void sendGet() throws Exception {

        String url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=developer";

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

        // add request header
        request.addHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + 
                       response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                       new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }

        System.out.println(result.toString());

    }

    // HTTP POST request
    private void sendPost() throws Exception {

        String url = "https://selfsolve.apple.com/wcResults.do";

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

        // add header
        post.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sn", "C02G8416DRJM"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cn", ""));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("locale", ""));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("caller", ""));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("num", "12345"));

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + post.getEntity());
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + 
                                    response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }

        System.out.println(result.toString());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. I wanted to send data via POST.
I used the following code:

```
    URL url = new URL("http://example.com/getval.php");
    Map<String,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    params.put("param1", param1);
    params.put("param2", param2);

    StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
    for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
        if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
        postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        postData.append('=');
        postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
    }
    String urlParameters = postData.toString();
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

    writer.write(urlParameters);
    writer.flush();

    String result = "";
    String line;
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        result += line;
    }
    writer.close();
    reader.close()
    System.out.println(result);
```

I used Jsoup for parse:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(value);
    Iterator<Element> opts = doc.select("option").iterator();
    for (;opts.hasNext();) {
        Element item = opts.next();
        if (item.hasAttr("value")) {
            System.out.println(item.attr("value"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this pattern:

```
public static PricesResponse getResponse(EventRequestRaw request) {

    // String urlParameters  = "param1=a&param2=b&param3=c";
    String urlParameters = Piping.serialize(request);

    HttpURLConnection conn = RestClient.getPOSTConnection(endPoint, urlParameters);

    PricesResponse response = null;

    try {
        // POST
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        writer.write(urlParameters);
        writer.flush();

        // RESPONSE
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String json = Buffering.getString(reader);
        response = (PricesResponse) Piping.deserialize(json, PricesResponse.class);

        writer.close();
        reader.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    conn.disconnect();

    System.out.println("PricesClient: " + response.toString());

    return response;
}

public static HttpURLConnection getPOSTConnection(String endPoint, String urlParameters) {

    return RestClient.getConnection(endPoint, "POST", urlParameters);

}


public static HttpURLConnection getConnection(String endPoint, String method, String urlParameters) {

    System.out.println("ENDPOINT " + endPoint + " METHOD " + method);
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(endPoint);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod(method);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return conn;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer covers the specific case of the POST Call using a Custom Java POJO.

Using maven dependency for [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson#gson) to serialize our Java Object to JSON.

Install Gson using the dependency below.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
  <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.5</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

For those using gradle can use the below

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}
```

Other imports used:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.*;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
```

Now, we can go ahead and use the HttpPost provided by [Apache](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e37)

```
private CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://example.com");

Product product = new Product(); //custom java object to be posted as Request Body
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String client = gson.toJson(product);

    httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(client, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    httppost.setHeader("RANDOM-HEADER", "headervalue");
    //Execute and get the response.
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new InternalServerErrorException("Post fails");
    }
    Response.Status responseStatus = Response.Status.fromStatusCode(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    return Response.status(responseStatus).build();
```

The above code will return with the response code received from the POST Call

Answer (score 2):

here i sent jsonobject as parameter //jsonobject={"name":"lucifer","pass":"abc"}//serverUrl = "http://192.168.100.12/testing" //host=192.168.100.12

```
  public static String getJson(String serverUrl,String host,String jsonobject){

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String http = serverUrl;

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(http);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(50000);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(50000);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Host", host);
        urlConnection.connect();
        //You Can also Create JSONObject here 
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        out.write(jsonobject);// here i sent the parameter
        out.close();
        int HttpResult = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (HttpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    urlConnection.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            br.close();
            Log.e("new Test", "" + sb.toString());
            return sb.toString();
        } else {
            Log.e(" ", "" + urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null)
            urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hello pls use this class to improve your post method

```
public static JSONObject doPostRequest(HashMap<String, String> data, String url) {

    try {
        RequestBody requestBody;
        MultipartBuilder mBuilder = new MultipartBuilder().type(MultipartBuilder.FORM);

        if (data != null) {


            for (String key : data.keySet()) {
                String value = data.get(key);
                Utility.printLog("Key Values", key + "-----------------" + value);

                mBuilder.addFormDataPart(key, value);

            }
        } else {
            mBuilder.addFormDataPart("temp", "temp");
        }
        requestBody = mBuilder.build();


        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        String responseBody = response.body().string();
        Utility.printLog("URL", url);
        Utility.printLog("Response", responseBody);
        return new JSONObject(responseBody);

    } catch (UnknownHostException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();

        try {
            jsonObject.put("status","false");
            jsonObject.put("message",e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();

        try {
            jsonObject.put("status","false");
            jsonObject.put("message",e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "Other Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I higly recomend [http-request](https://github.com/jsunsoftware/http-request) built on apache http api.

For your case you can see example:

```
private static final HttpRequest<String.class> HTTP_REQUEST = 
      HttpRequestBuilder.createPost("http://example.com/index.php", String.class)
           .responseDeserializer(ResponseDeserializer.ignorableDeserializer())
           .build();

public void sendRequest(String request){
     String parameters = request.split("\\?")[1];
     ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = 
            HTTP_REQUEST.executeWithQuery(parameters);

   System.out.println(responseHandler.getStatusCode());
   System.out.println(responseHandler.get()); //prints response body
}
```

If you are not interested in the response body

```
private static final HttpRequest<?> HTTP_REQUEST = 
     HttpRequestBuilder.createPost("http://example.com/index.php").build();

public void sendRequest(String request){
     ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = 
           HTTP_REQUEST.executeWithQuery(parameters);
}
```

For general sending post request with [http-request](https://github.com/jsunsoftware/http-request): Read the documentation and see my answers [HTTP POST request with JSON String in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20740349/http-post-request-with-json-string-in-java/46280179#46280179), [Sending HTTP POST Request In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324717/sending-http-post-request-in-java/46263882#46263882), [HTTP POST using JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181534/http-post-using-json-in-java/46342805#46342805)

Answer (score 0):

I took Boann's answer and used it to create a more flexible query string builder that supports lists and arrays, just like php's http_build_query method:

```
public static byte[] httpBuildQueryString(Map<String, Object> postsData) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
    for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : postsData.entrySet()) {
        if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');

        Object value = param.getValue();
        String key = param.getKey();

        if(value instanceof Object[] || value instanceof List<?>)
        {
            int size = value instanceof Object[] ? ((Object[])value).length : ((List<?>)value).size();
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                Object val = value instanceof Object[] ? ((Object[])value)[i] : ((List<?>)value).get(i);
                if(i>0) postData.append('&');
                postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(key + "[" + i + "]", "UTF-8"));
                postData.append('=');            
                postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(val), "UTF-8"));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
            postData.append('=');            
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(value), "UTF-8"));
        }
    }
    return postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those having trouble receiving the request on a php page using $_POST because you expect key-value pairs:

While all the answers where very helpful, I lacked some basic understanding on which string actually to post, since in the old apache HttpClient I used

```
new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs); (Java)
```

and then could use $_POST in php do get the key-value pairs.

To my understanding now one has build that string manually before posting. So the string needs to look like

```
val data = "key1=val1&key2=val2"
```

but instead just adding it to the url it is posted (in the header).

The alternative would be to use a json-string instead:

```
val data = "{\"key1\":\"val1\",\"key2\":\"val2\"}" // {"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}
```

and pull it in php without $_POST:

```
$json_params = file_get_contents('php://input');
// echo_p("Data: $json_params");
$data = json_decode($json_params, true);
```

Here you find a sample code in Kotlin:

```
class TaskDownloadTest : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void): Void? {
        var urlConnection: HttpURLConnection? = null

        try {

            val postData = JsonObject()
            postData.addProperty("key1", "val1")
            postData.addProperty("key2", "val2")

            // reformat json to key1=value1&key2=value2
            // keeping json because I may change the php part to interpret json requests, could be a HashMap instead
            val keys = postData.keySet()
            var request = ""
            keys.forEach { key ->
                // Log.i("data", key)
                request += "$key=${postData.get(key)}&"
            }
            request = request.replace("\"", "").removeSuffix("&")
            val requestLength = request.toByteArray().size
            // Warning in Android 9 you need to add a line in the application part of the manifest: android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted
            val url = URL("http://10.0.2.2/getdata.php")
            urlConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            // urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") // apparently default
            // Not sure what these are for, I do not use them
            // urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
            // urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Key","Value")
            urlConnection.readTimeout = 5000
            urlConnection.connectTimeout = 5000
            urlConnection.requestMethod = "POST"
            urlConnection.doOutput = true
            // urlConnection.doInput = true
            urlConnection.useCaches = false
            urlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(requestLength)
            // urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0) // if you do not want to handle request length which is fine for small requests

            val out = urlConnection.outputStream
            val writer = BufferedWriter(
                OutputStreamWriter(
                    out, "UTF-8"
                )
            )
            writer.write(request)
            // writer.write("{\"key1\":\"val1\",\"key2\":\"val2\"}") // {"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"} JsonFormat or just postData.toString() for $json_params=file_get_contents('php://input'); json_decode($json_params, true); in php
            // writer.write("key1=val1&key2=val2") // key=value format for $_POST in php
            writer.flush()
            writer.close()
            out.close()

            val code = urlConnection.responseCode
            if (code != 200) {
                throw IOException("Invalid response from server: $code")
            }

            val rd = BufferedReader(
                InputStreamReader(
                    urlConnection.inputStream
                )
            )
            var line = rd.readLine()
            while (line != null) {
                Log.i("data", line)
                line = rd.readLine()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } finally {
            urlConnection?.disconnect()
        }

        return null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I had to do an HTTP request class, it is probably not the most efficient class, but it works.
I collected some codes from this page and made it more dynamic.

Anyone who needs a complete code, I attached it below.
For an example of how to use it, you can look at the `main` method.

Also, if you are willing to improve classes online, you are more than welcome to help me make this class better.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;
import java.io.*;
  
public class HttpRequest {
    
    
    String result = "";
    
    HttpRequest(String _url, String _method, Map<String, String> _postData, String _contentType) {
        
        try {
            URL url = new URL( _url );
            URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
            HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)con;
            http.setRequestMethod(_method); // PUT is another valid option
            http.setDoOutput(true);         
            
            StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner("&");
            for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : _postData.entrySet())
                sj.add(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8") + "=" + entry.getValue());
                //sj.add(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue()));
            byte[] out = sj.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            int length = out.length;
            http.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(length);
            http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", _contentType);
            http.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
            http.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( length ));
            http.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
            http.setUseCaches( false );
            http.connect();
            try(OutputStream os = http.getOutputStream()) {
                os.write(out);
            }
            if (http.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(http.getInputStream()))) {
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                  result = result + line;
                }
            }
          } else {
            System.out.println("Bad response!");
          }
        }catch (IOException e) {
            // writing exception to log
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    
    
    HttpRequest(String _url, String _method, Map<String, String> _postData) {
        this(_url, _method, _postData, "text/html");
    }
    
    HttpRequest(String _url, String _method) {
        this(_url, _method, new HashMap<String, String>());
    }
    
    HttpRequest(String _url) {
        this(_url, "GET");
    }
    
    
    public String toString() {
        return result;
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Map<String, String> postData = new HashMap<String, String>();
        postData.putIfAbsent("email", "test@test.com");
        postData.putIfAbsent("password", "test");
        
        HttpRequest result = new HttpRequest("https://httpbin.org/anything", "POST", postData, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        System.out.println(result.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the new [HTTP Client API](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html) available in Java 11 and higher ([except on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65363995/8583692)).

```java
var myData = "{ myParam1: 'This is cool' }"; // OR, "myParam1=abc&myParam2=xxx"
var uri = URI.create("https://httpbin.org/post");
var client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
var request = HttpRequest
        .newBuilder()
        .uri(uri)
        .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
        .timeout(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json") // OR text/plain
        .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(myData))
        .build();
var response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

##### The same request executed asynchronously:

```java
var responseAsync = client
        .sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
        .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
        .thenAccept(System.out::println);
// responseAsync.join(); // Wait for completion
```

To send data as multipart (`multipart/form-data`) format, see [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56482187/8583692).
To send data as url-encoded (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) format, see [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56728398/8583692).

See [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-http-client) for examples and more information about HTTP Client API.

##### For Java standard library HTTP **server**, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71635295/8583692).

Answer (score -1):

Appears that you also have to call`connection.getOutputStream()` "at least once" (as well as `setDoOutput(true)`) for it to treat it as a POST.

So the minimum required code is:

```
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    //connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); this doesn't seem to do anything at all..so not useful
    connection.setDoOutput(true); // set it to POST...not enough by itself however, also need the getOutputStream call...
    connection.connect();
    connection.getOutputStream().close();
```

You can even use "GET" style parameters in the urlString, surprisingly.  Though that might confuse things.

You can also use [NameValuePair](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13486223/32453) apparently.

Comment: Where are POST parameters... ?

Comment: Why are people downvoting this?  It's a note for how to do POST's at all, though without parameters...(i.e. no payload0...