# How to download com.sun.net.httpserver package?

Tags: java, android, com.sun.net.httpserver

I'm not familiar with where I can get the package com.sun.net.httpserver?  I like to use this package in Android.

Thanks!

Comment: why you want this package in your app ?

Comment: This contains a HttpServer classes for building a simple server.  I like to have that functionality.

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttp221jar.htm  - I download all my java libraries from java2s.com

Comment: [*JEP 408: Simple Web Server*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/408)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It's part of Java SE 6](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/package-summary.html). It's not published separately and also not included in Android. I'd suggest to look for another lightweight Java implementation of a HTTP server, like [i-Jetty](http://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I actually now understand where this packages come from :P

Answer (score 13):

You can download it from:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20090716001955/http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/sun/net/httpserver/http/20070405/http-20070405.jar

It used to be available from Sun for Java 5 but they seem to have pulled the link. It has been archived though. Don't know if it works on Android mind you.

Old, broken links:

- https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/download_file?file_path=com%2Fsun%2Fnet%2Fhttpserver%2Fhttp%2F20070405%2Fhttp-20070405.jar
- http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/sun/net/httpserver/http/20070405/http-20070405.jar

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. I didn't need it to work on Android; I only needed it for a test harness.

Comment: bintray is now a broken link

Answer (score 3):

Android studio use `jcenter` as the default repository source. The more convenient way is adding the dependency to gralde configuration.

The library can be found in `jcenter`, see [here](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.sun.net.httpserver%3Ahttp/20070405/view).

So just add it to your project's dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // ...
    compile 'com.sun.net.httpserver:http:20070405'
    // ...
}
```