# httpserver - library doesn't load

Tags: http, httpserver

I am only trying use java for some httpserver.
But I have quiet big problem.
I want to use httpserver sun.
[How to download com.sun.net.httpserver package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484989/how-to-download-com-sun-net-httpserver-package)

But when I included it to eclipse 1.7 JE , It doesn't work.
http://imgup.cz/image/GHj -> JAVA - eclipse
http://pastebin.com/U9nWjjVc -> CODE
It is not my first external jar library, which I included, Soo.
I don't know where is problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the file, Eclipse sometimes still shows errors you fixed until you actually save the file.

I recommend you also download a [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) since it contains the source code for the System Libraries.