# Apache Commons Math ' SummaryStatistics cannot be resolved to a type '

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-math

I am attempting to use Apache Commons Math 3.3 for a static data processing class, and am using Eclipse Mars to create it. I have successfully downloaded the bin and src files, and added them to the build path of my project; I can see them in my JRE System Library. I have also added the javadoc URL in the 'Javadoc Location' tab. I am successful in importing classes from the library.

However, when I attempt to instantiate an object from AC-M, Eclipse is unable to resolve that object as a type. For instance,

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.stat.descriptive.SummaryStatistics.*;

public class Stats {

public static double mean(double[] data) {
    SummaryStatistics curr = new SummaryStatistics();
    for (int a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {
        curr.addValue(data[a]);
    }
    double mn = curr.getMean();
    return mn;}

}
```

The import statement works fine. However, immediately Eclipse reads an error in my 4th line of code:

SummaryStatistics cannot be resolved to a type

This occurs for all other objects, e.g. `PearsonsCorrelation`, `SimpleRegression`, etc. (I successfully import the respective portions of the library for all objects.) Eclipse offers an option to 'Fix project setup..', yet upon clicking, no solutions are available. I have cleaned the buildpath to no avail. I would appreciate assistance in fixing this problem.

EDIT: I added the jar files by selecting the package of interest and clicking Properties>JRE System Library [jre8] Edit...>Installed JREs...>Edit...>Add External JARs...then adding commons-math3-3.3.jar to the library.

Comment: Care to show how you say you have included the apache commons library in the java buildpath of your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This import:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.stat.descriptive.SummaryStatistics.*;
```

doesn't import `SummaryStatistics` itself, just any classes defined within that class. Add:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.stat.descriptive.SummaryStatistics;
```

as well.

Comment: Thank you @Joe. When I do this, Eclipse reads an error 'Access restriction: The type 'SummaryStatistics' is not 
 API (restriction on required library 'C:\Users\Dan
 \Documents\AC-M\commons-math3-3.3.jar')'.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824515/how-to-add-external-library-properly-in-eclipse ; don't add external libraries to your JRE or you'll trigger http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266632/access-restriction-is-not-accessible-due-to-restriction-on-required-library .

Answer (score -1):

It was caused by the fact that Eclipse environment was set not to build
automatically (Project -> Build Automatically).

Even though I was adding a correct JARs (through Project - Properties - Java
Build Path - Libraries), Eclipse did not rebuild, meaning it didn't
recalculate new dependencies (and didn't apply them on the existing source).

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/67910/