# JFrame is not recognised by eclipse

Tags: java, jframe

I am trying to create an example with JFrame, but when i write JFrame in eclipse, it gets underscored by red line as if it is not defined, how can I solve this issue:

**code**:

```
package openCVExamples;

public class OpenCVTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame j = new JFrame();        
  }
}
```

**update**:

when hover over JFrame keyword, eclipse says

```
:Access restriction: the type     
JFrame is not accessible due to restriction on required library 
c:?\programfiles\java\jre1.8.0_40\lib\rt.jar
```

Comment: Please copy/paste your code here.

Comment: @lisztomania the code posted

Comment: When I paste your code in my eclipse ... JFrame is underlined; then I press "ctrl-shift-o"; the import statement is added and the red line is added.
So, next step: turn to the "problems" view and copy/paste the error message you get for the import statement here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar

Comment: Or if that thing somehow vanished into thin air - consider deleting the question.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely; you did not **import** the JFrame class.

You can simply press "ctrl-shift-o" to "organize" your import statements. Eclipse will automatically add all required imports.

JFrame is a class that belongs to the "default" set of classes for Java. If it can't be found/imported, then your "project setup" is broken somehow.

Comment: import javax.swing.*; i unrecognisable by eclipse as well

Comment: Then your project is somehow broken. You could try the **2nd** answer given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266632/access-restriction-is-not-accessible-due-to-restriction-on-required-library

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the JFrame class. You can write:

```
package OpenCVExamples;

import javax.swing.*;

public class OpenCVTest{
     //your code
}
```

at the top of your file, but after the package line.

You can also do it automatically by pressing Ctrl+Shift+O to import all the classes you need.

Comment: import javax.swing.*; i unrecognisable by eclipse as well

Comment: Normally when you begin to write import javax. the eclipse editor proposes you a list of choices including javax.swing.* That is pretty weird that eclipse does not recognize it. Are you sure you have no syntax errors before this line?

Comment: when you pass your mouse pointer on the red lines of  JFrame, does the editor proposes you a solution?

Comment: Then you should write the import line after the package line.

Comment: when hover over JFrame keyword, eclipse says :Access restriction: the type JFrame is not accessible due to restriction on required library c:?\programfiles\java\jre1.8.0_40\lib\rt.jar

Answer (score 0):

> Project -> Properties -> Libraries
>
> Remove the rt.jar file
>
> Click on "Add external JARs.."
>
> Re-add the rt.jar file (located at C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_20\lib)

If it still does not work, you might want to try a different Java Runtime Environment. I had the same problem and what fixed it for me was importing the rt.jar file located at C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib.