# Getting Access restriction error while maven build

Tags: eclipse, maven, tycho

Here I'm getting Access restriction error while building my multi-module maven project.

Adding the error details:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:1.0.0:compile (default-compile) on project my.project.ui.core.communication: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] C:\HOME\SOME_DIR\my.project.ui.core.communication\src\my\project\ui\core\communication\logic\RequirementLibraryDelegate.java:[474]
[ERROR] LOGGER.severe(IRequirementLibraryLogIds.REQLIBMSGID0009, e.getMessage() + e);
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] Access restriction: The method 'EJBException.getMessage()' is not API (restriction on classpath entry 'C:\HOME\SOME_DIR\my.project.common.server\lib\j2ee.jar')
```

Reference which i have already tried: [Access restriction: Is not accessible due to restriction on required library ..\jre\lib\rt.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266632/access-restriction-is-not-accessible-due-to-restriction-on-required-library)

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the following target in pom.xml.

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

If it doesn't help, use in MANIFEST.MF a specific OSGi depedency via Import-Package like this:

```
Import-Package: org.eclipse.jface.contentassist
```