# How to obtain the query string in a GET with Java HttpServer/HttpExchange?

Tags: java, get, query-string, httpserver

I am trying to create a simple HttpServer in Java to handle GET requests,
but when I try to get the GET parameters for a request I noticed the HttpExchange class does not have a method for that.

Does anybody know an easy way to read the GET parameters (query string)?

This is how my handler looks like:

```
public class TestHandler{
  @Override
  public void handle(HttpExchange exc) throws IOxception {
    String response = "This is the reponse";
    exc.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());

    // need GET params here

    OutputStream os = exc.getResponseBody();
    os.write(response.getBytes());
    os.close();
  } 
}
```

.. and the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
  // create server on port 8000
  InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(8000);
  HttpServer server = new HttpServer.create(address, 0);

  // bind handler
  server.createContext("/highscore", new TestHandler());
  server.setExecutor(null);
  server.start();
}
```

Comment: An easy way? Parse the URI; it's just a get request. If you have to handle posts, things like [this](http://leonardom.wordpress.com/2009/08/06/getting-parameters-from-httpexchange/) might help.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The following: `httpExchange.getRequestURI().getQuery()`

will return string in format similar to this: `"field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3..."`

so you could simply parse string yourself, this is how function for parsing could look like:

```
public Map<String, String> queryToMap(String query) {
    if(query == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (String param : query.split("&")) {
        String[] entry = param.split("=");
        if (entry.length > 1) {
            result.put(entry[0], entry[1]);
        }else{
            result.put(entry[0], "");
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And this is how you could use it:

```
Map<String, String> params = queryToMap(httpExchange.getRequestURI().getQuery()); 
System.out.println("param A=" + params.get("A"));
```

Comment: Important to know: The query could be null. You should check that.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! It fails for params whose value includes an ampersand, though. To fix, use `getRawQuery()` instead of `getQuery()`, then `param = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(param, "UTF-8")` after splitting on "&".

Comment: @Evan, I believe the decoding should happen when putting the value into the Map - that way you don't lose part of the value if there's an '=' in it.

Comment: This does not properly deencode the strings, `URLDecoder` should have been used.

Comment: It should be `param.split("=", 2);` in case the value contains a *=*.
(btw this solution does not support double keys like *x=111&x=222*)

Comment: @Datz, having the same key in query param is even valid? can you add any use case?

Comment: @ssi-anik try for example this URL: `https://www.google.com/?q=hello&q=ssi-anik`
Many framework/programming languages create an array of the values. (eg `q[0]=hello  q[1]=ssi-anik`

Answer (score 3):

This answer, contrary to annon01's, properly decodes the keys and values. It does not use `String.split`, but scans the string using `indexOf`, which is faster.

```
public static Map<String, String> parseQueryString(String qs) {
    Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
    if (qs == null)
        return result;

    int last = 0, next, l = qs.length();
    while (last < l) {
        next = qs.indexOf('&', last);
        if (next == -1)
            next = l;

        if (next > last) {
            int eqPos = qs.indexOf('=', last);
            try {
                if (eqPos < 0 || eqPos > next)
                    result.put(URLDecoder.decode(qs.substring(last, next), "utf-8"), "");
                else
                    result.put(URLDecoder.decode(qs.substring(last, eqPos), "utf-8"), URLDecoder.decode(qs.substring(eqPos + 1, next), "utf-8"));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e); // will never happen, utf-8 support is mandatory for java
            }
        }
        last = next + 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answer by @anon01, this is how to do it in Groovy:

```
Map<String,String> getQueryParameters( HttpExchange httpExchange )
{
    def query = httpExchange.getRequestURI().getQuery()
    return query.split( '&' )
            .collectEntries {
        String[] pair = it.split( '=' )
        if (pair.length > 1)
        {
            return [(pair[0]): pair[1]]
        }
        else
        {
            return [(pair[0]): ""]
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how to use it:

```
def queryParameters = getQueryParameters( httpExchange )
def parameterA = queryParameters['A']
```

Comment: Well, thank you. But the question is for Java, not Goovy ;)

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled across this, and figured I'd toss a [Java 8 / Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) implementation out here, whilst adding a few extra bits (not in previous answers).

**Extra 1**: I've added a filter to avoid processing any empty params. Something that should not happen, but it allows a cleaner implementation vs. not handling the issue (and sending an empty response). An example of this would look like `?param1=value1&param2=`

**Extra 2**: I've leveraged [String.split(String regex, int limit)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) for the second split operation. This allows a query parameter such as `?param1=it_has=in-it&other=something` to be passed.

```
public static Map<String, String> getParamMap(String query) {
    // query is null if not provided (e.g. localhost/path )
    // query is empty if '?' is supplied (e.g. localhost/path? )
    if (query == null || query.isEmpty()) return Collections.emptyMap();

    return Stream.of(query.split("&"))
            .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
            .map(kv -> kv.split("=", 2)) 
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x[0], x-> x[1]));

}
```

**Imports**

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
```

Answer (score 1):

If, like me, your query string allows the same name to occur multiple times, the you'll want the values to be lists (like in Netty's `QueryStringDecoder`). Adapted from the best answer here..

```
  final static Charset UTF_8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

  static Map<String, List<String>> queryMap(HttpExchange exchange) {
    return queryMap(exchange.getRequestURI().getRawQuery());
  }
  
  static Map<String, List<String>> queryMap(String query) {
    if (query == null || query.isEmpty()) {
      return Map.of();
    }
    Map<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (String param : query.split("&")) {
      String[] entry = param.split("=");
      var name = entry[0];
      var list = result.get(name);
      if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<>(2);
        result.put(name, list);
      }
      String value = entry.length > 1 ?
            URLDecoder.decode(entry[1], UTF_8) : "";
      
      list.add(value);
    }
    return result;
  }
```