# Servlet 3.0 without a WAR file?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, jetty, servlet-3.0

Is it possible to launch a webapp altogether with:

1) No war file:

http://stephenh.github.io/2009/01/10/war-less-dev-with-jetty.html
http://www.jamesward.com/2011/08/23/war-less-java-web-apps

2) No web.xml (i.e., Servlet-3.0)

3) From an embedded web container (e.g., Tomcat or Jetty...)

Comment: You can "deploy" a JAX-WS service without container!

Comment: Just looking for a simple webapp setup to handle basic browser http requests... (not SOAP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I did it (embedded SpringMVC + Jetty, no web.xml no war files):

Use Spring's `@WebAppConfiguration` to bootstrap your `WebApplicationContext` with a `MockServletContext`,

then simply register your `new DispatcherServlet(WebApplicationContext)` via Jetty's ServletContextHandler/ServletHolder mechanism. Easy!

Answer (score 2):

Example Project: https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-servlet-3.0

You'll still need a `WEB-INF/web.xml`, but [it can be empty](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-servlet-3.0/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml).  This is so that the servlet support level and metadata-complete flags can be known.

Example: empty Servlet 3.0 web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    metadata-complete="false"
    version="3.0">
</web-app>
```

Then you can follow the [EmbedMe.java](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-servlet-3.0/blob/master/src/test/java/com/company/foo/EmbedMe.java) for an example on how to set this up.

```java
public class EmbedMe {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int port = 8080;
        Server server = new Server(port);

        String wardir = "target/sample-webapp-1-SNAPSHOT";

        WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
        context.setResourceBase(wardir);
        context.setDescriptor(wardir + "WEB-INF/web.xml");
        context.setConfigurations(new Configuration[] {
                new AnnotationConfiguration(), new WebXmlConfiguration(),
                new WebInfConfiguration(), new TagLibConfiguration(),
                new PlusConfiguration(), new MetaInfConfiguration(),
                new FragmentConfiguration(), new EnvConfiguration() });

        context.setContextPath("/");
        context.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
        server.setHandler(context);
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I'm getting a 404 Error trying to access localhost:8080 (I'm running this from Eclipse, simply as "Java Application").
I'm also using the latest http://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-servlet-3.0 :(

Comment: Try command line on that project ...  $ mvn clean install exec:exec

Comment: Will I still have to apply this workaround: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404176
to use the "AnnotationConfig()" you've shown outside of WEB-INF/?

Comment: This solution packages as a WAR

Comment: @fionbio its an exploded webapp directory. a WAR is a web archive.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to  achieve an embedded server with Jetty that doesn't require a WAR or any XML. You just have to specify where your annotated classes will be, adding an extra class path.

This method should be called from a main you can name `Server.java`:

```
private static void startServer() throws Exception {
    final org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server server = new org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server(7070);
    final WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext("/", "/");
    context.setConfigurations(new Configuration[] { new AnnotationConfiguration(), new WebInfConfiguration() });
    context.setExtraClasspath("build/classes/main/com/example/servlet");
    server.setHandler(context);
    server.start();
    server.join();
}
```

My `src` structure was:

```
-main
  -java
    -com.example
      -json
      -servlet
      -filter
      -util
      Server.java
```

I would like to see a similar solution with Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer of [BalusC](http://balusc.blogspot.mx/) for [simple HTTP server in Java using only Java SE API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732109/simple-http-server-in-java-using-only-java-se-api). The example is using the class [`com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html).

Comment: Not quite what I'm seeking; I'm essentially trying to programmatically load a webapp (not a simple manual HttpServer) into an embedded web container without having to deploy a "war file" or even having a web.xml. Specifically, a Spring WebApplicationContext...