# Is there a bridge between Servlets and Suns simple HTTP Server

Tags: java, servlets, httpserver

I have an existing application which uses [Sun/Oracle's simple HTTP Server](https://blogs.oracle.com/michaelmcm/entry/http_server_api_in_java) and I cannot easily change that. Now I would like to add an existing Servlet implementation as part of this http server, however the simple HTTP Server obviously does not support the full Servlet specification and thus there is no direct way of adding the Servlet.

So is there a piece of code available somewhere to at least run a basic Servlet via some sort of bridge from the [HttpHandler](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpHandler.html) to a normal Servlet?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20261540/2970947) you go.

Comment: Thanks a lot, please add this as answer so I can confirm that this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code comes from [f.carlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2348095/f-carlsen) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20261540/2970947), and I've used it myself.

```
class HttpHandlerWithServletSupport implements HttpHandler {
    private HttpServlet servlet;

    private final class RequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
        private final HttpExchange ex;
        private final Map<String, String[]> postData;
        private final ServletInputStream is;
        private final Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();

        private RequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request, HttpExchange ex,
                Map<String, String[]> postData, ServletInputStream is) {
            super(request);
            this.ex = ex;
            this.postData = postData;
            this.is = is;
        }

        @Override
        public String getHeader(String name) {
            return ex.getRequestHeaders().getFirst(name);
        }

        @Override
        public Enumeration<String> getHeaders(String name) {
            return new Vector<String>(ex.getRequestHeaders().get(name))
                    .elements();
        }

        @Override
        public Enumeration<String> getHeaderNames() {
            return new Vector<String>(ex.getRequestHeaders().keySet())
                    .elements();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getAttribute(String name) {
            return attributes.get(name);
        }

        @Override
        public void setAttribute(String name, Object o) {
            this.attributes.put(name, o);
        }

        @Override
        public Enumeration<String> getAttributeNames() {
            return new Vector<String>(attributes.keySet()).elements();
        }

        @Override
        public String getMethod() {
            return ex.getRequestMethod();
        }

        @Override
        public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return is;
        }

        @Override
        public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
            return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    getInputStream()));
        }

        @Override
        public String getPathInfo() {
            return ex.getRequestURI().getPath();
        }

        @Override
        public String getParameter(String name) {
            String[] arr = postData.get(name);
            return arr != null ? (arr.length > 1 ? Arrays.toString(arr)
                    : arr[0]) : null;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap() {
            return postData;
        }

        @Override
        public Enumeration<String> getParameterNames() {
            return new Vector<String>(postData.keySet()).elements();
        }
    }

    private final class ResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {
        final ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = new ServletOutputStream() {

            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                outputStream.write(b);
            }
        };

        private final HttpExchange ex;
        private final PrintWriter printWriter;
        private int status = HttpServletResponse.SC_OK;

        private ResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response,
                HttpExchange ex) {
            super(response);
            this.ex = ex;
            printWriter = new PrintWriter(servletOutputStream);
        }

        @Override
        public void setContentType(String type) {
            ex.getResponseHeaders().add("Content-Type", type);
        }

        @Override
        public void setHeader(String name, String value) {
            ex.getResponseHeaders().add(name, value);
        }

        @Override
        public javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream getOutputStream()
                throws IOException {
            return servletOutputStream;
        }

        @Override
        public void setContentLength(int len) {
            ex.getResponseHeaders().add("Content-Length", len + "");
        }

        @Override
        public void setStatus(int status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        @Override
        public void sendError(int sc, String msg) throws IOException {
            this.status = sc;
            if (msg != null) {
                printWriter.write(msg);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void sendError(int sc) throws IOException {
            sendError(sc, null);
        }

        @Override
        public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
            return printWriter;
        }

        public void complete() throws IOException {
            try {
                printWriter.flush();
                ex.sendResponseHeaders(status, outputStream.size());
                if (outputStream.size() > 0) {
                    ex.getResponseBody().write(outputStream.toByteArray());
                }
                ex.getResponseBody().flush();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                ex.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public HttpHandlerWithServletSupport(HttpServlet servlet) {
        this.servlet = servlet;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void handle(final HttpExchange ex) throws IOException {
        byte[] inBytes = getBytes(ex.getRequestBody());
        ex.getRequestBody().close();
        final ByteArrayInputStream newInput = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                inBytes);
        final ServletInputStream is = new ServletInputStream() {

            @Override
            public int read() throws IOException {
                return newInput.read();
            }
        };

        Map<String, String[]> parsePostData = new HashMap<>();

        try {
            parsePostData.putAll(HttpUtils.parseQueryString(ex
                    .getRequestURI().getQuery()));

            // check if any postdata to parse
            parsePostData.putAll(HttpUtils
                    .parsePostData(inBytes.length, is));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // no postData - just reset inputstream
            newInput.reset();
        }
        final Map<String, String[]> postData = parsePostData;

        RequestWrapper req = new RequestWrapper(
                createUnimplementAdapter(HttpServletRequest.class), ex,
                postData, is);

        ResponseWrapper resp = new ResponseWrapper(
                createUnimplementAdapter(HttpServletResponse.class), ex);

        try {
            servlet.service(req, resp);
            resp.complete();
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
    }

    private static byte[] getBytes(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (true) {
            int r = in.read(buffer);
            if (r == -1)
                break;
            out.write(buffer, 0, r);
        }
        return out.toByteArray();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static <T> T createUnimplementAdapter(Class<T> httpServletApi) {
        class UnimplementedHandler implements InvocationHandler {
            @Override
            public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)
                    throws Throwable {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented: "
                        + method + ", args=" + Arrays.toString(args));
            }
        }

        return (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                UnimplementedHandler.class.getClassLoader(),
                new Class<?>[] { httpServletApi },
                new UnimplementedHandler());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is missing some methods on ServletOutputStream and ServletInputStream

Comment: @HomeIsWhereThePcIs It worked with whatever version of the servlet spec we were using in 2014!