# Is it possible to use com.sun.net.httpserver package in android program?

Tags: android

I wanna to create an HTTP server in Android. I want to use com.sun.net.httpserver in this program. In your opinion, Is it possible to use this package in Android program? 
I wrote a service to do this. My program is as fallow:

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class HSMainService extends Service {

    //region constants
    public static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    public static final int SERVERPORT = 8080;
    //endregion
    //************************
    //region instance variables
    private String TAG;
    private Uri soundURI = Uri
            .parse("android.resource://com.ebcompany.hs4/"
                    + R.raw.alarm_rooster);
    private long[] mVibratePattern = { 0, 200, 200, 300 };

    private HttpServer server;
    //endregion
    //************************
    //region constructors
    public HSMainService() {
        //TAG = getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.log_message_tag);
    }
    //endregion
    //************************
    //region override methods
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    // This is the old onStart method that will be called on the pre-2.0
    // platform.  On 2.0 or later we override onStartCommand() so this
    // method will not be called.
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        //handleCommand(intent);
        Log.i(TAG, "onStart");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onStart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //handleCommand(intent);
        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
        // stopped, so return sticky.
        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        //Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TestActivity.class);
        //in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        //startActivity(in);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onStartCommand", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Context cntx = getApplicationContext();
        TAG = cntx.getString(R.string.log_message_tag);
        Log.i(TAG, "Service creating");
        final Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new    Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setContentInfo("HS4")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setContentTitle(cntx.getString(R.string.notification_content_title))
                .setContentText(cntx.getString(R.string.notification_content_text))
                .setTicker(cntx.getString(R.string.notification_tiker_text))
                .setSound(soundURI)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setLargeIcon((((BitmapDrawable)    this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fire_eye_alien)).getBitmap()));
        final NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        mNotificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                notificationBuilder.build());
        try {
            server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(SERVERPORT), 0);
            server.createContext("IS2", new IS2Handler());
            server.createContext("DSP", new DSPHandler());
            server.setExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(0x5) ); // creates a default executor
            server.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG, "Service destroying");
        //server.stop(0x1);
    }
    //endregion
    //************************
}
```

When I run this program I get this error:

```
08-02 04:24:37.233    2994-2994/com.ebcompany.hs4 I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method sun.misc.Service.providers, referenced from method com.sun.net.httpserver.spi.HttpServerProvider.loadProviderAsService
08-02 04:24:37.233    2994-2994/com.ebcompany.hs4 W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 421: Lsun/misc/Service;.providers (Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Ljava/util/Iterator;
08-02 04:24:37.233    2994-2994/com.ebcompany.hs4 E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'sun.misc.ServiceConfigurationError', referenced from method com.sun.net.httpserver.spi.HttpServerProvider.loadProviderFromProperty
08-02 04:24:37.233    2994-2994/com.ebcompany.hs4 W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 155 (Lsun/misc/ServiceConfigurationError;) in Lcom/sun/net/httpserver/spi/HttpServerProvider;
08-02 04:24:37.233    2994-2994/com.ebcompany.hs4 E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'sun.misc.ServiceConfigurationError', referenced from method com.sun.net.httpserver.spi.HttpServerProvider.loadProviderFromProperty
08-02 04:24:37.233    2994-2994/com.ebcompany.hs4 W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 155 (Lsun/misc/ServiceConfigurationError;) in Lcom/sun/net/httpserver/spi/HttpServerProvider;
08-02 04:24:37.233    2994-2994/com.ebcompany.hs4 E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'sun.misc.ServiceConfigurationError', referenced from method com.sun.net.httpserver.spi.HttpServerProvider.loadProviderFromProperty
08-02 04:24:37.233    2994-2994/com.ebcompany.hs4 W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 155 (Lsun/misc/ServiceConfigurationError;) in Lcom/sun/net/httpserver/spi/HttpServerProvider;
08-02 04:24:37.233    2994-2994/com.ebcompany.hs4 E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'sun.misc.ServiceConfigurationError', referenced from method com.sun.net.httpserver.spi.HttpServerProvider.loadProviderFromProperty
08-02 04:24:37.233    2994-2994/com.ebcompany.hs4 W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 155 (Lsun/misc/ServiceConfigurationError;) in Lcom/sun/net/httpserver/spi/HttpServerProvider;
08-02 04:24:37.233    2994-2994/com.ebcompany.hs4 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xacd19b20)
08-02 04:24:37.233    2994-2994/com.ebcompany.hs4 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ebcompany.hs4, PID: 2994
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun.misc.Service
            at com.sun.net.httpserver.spi.HttpServerProvider.loadProviderAsService(HttpServerProvider.java:82)
            at com.sun.net.httpserver.spi.HttpServerProvider.access$200(HttpServerProvider.java:27)
            at com.sun.net.httpserver.spi.HttpServerProvider$1.run(HttpServerProvider.java:144)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:45)
            at com.sun.net.httpserver.spi.HttpServerProvider.provider(HttpServerProvider.java:139)
            at com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.create(HttpServer.java:110)
            at com.ebcompany.hs4.HSMainService.onCreate(HSMainService.java:93)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2572)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: In addition to finding the code, there are some other issues on Android - keeping the networking in the background, the fact that the service may not run continuously, needing a wifi lock or to occasionally generate your own traffic to keep it up, etc.  You may want to do a search for specifically Android solutions rather than trying to figure it out on your own.

Comment: Hi. My goal is create a locale network, but based on HTTP protocol. In my project, clients are local, and at most, there are 2 or 3 clients,not more. By running the service as a foreground, I think it can be run continuously.Is there any example to do this?

Answer (score 2):

As of 2021, I don't think the answers provided here give a straight forward solution. This is what worked for me:

- you need a `jar` file with `com.sun.net.httpserver...` classes AND other classes that are used by the above
- you need to tell Android Studio to look for those classes in that `jar` file in order to be able to import them in your `java` files in your app
- you need to request `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Procedure:

- copy the `jar` file into your app's libs folder (in my case, `c:\Android Projects\<Project Name>\app\libs`). Where do you find such a file? In any java distribution, so in my case I simply used the `rt.jar` file from my Android Studio's `jre\libs` folder (in my case `C:\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\rt.jar`). You may frown upon the fact that that is a 60 MB file, but the resulting `apk` was not significantly bigger than without the httpserver, so I assume the compiler only takes what it needs plus all dependencies.
- in your Android Studio project, open the view in Project view (see image 1)
  [image: switch to Project view]
- once you have copied the `rt.jar` file into `app/libs`, it should appear in your project view, if not, right click the app icon and click Reload from Disk (see image 2)
  [image: Reload from Disk]
- then you right click the icon of your new `rt.jar` file and select Add As Library (see image 3)
  [image: Add As Library]

I have tried stripping down the `rt.jar` file to something smaller, but even though my app could compile and run, the first instance where a method was called using any of the imported classes from `com.sun.net.*`, the app would crash (as in CRASH, not raise an exception). Thus you better include the entire `rt.jar` file. The example below taken from [Simple HTTP server in Java using only Java SE API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732109/simple-http-server-in-java-using-only-java-se-api)

Now you can import

```
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;
```

and in your app's Activity class, create a simple http server the following way:

```
    HttpServer server;

    static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
            System.out.println(t.toString());
            String response = "This is the response";
            t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
            OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
            os.write(response.getBytes());
            os.close();
        }
    }

...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        (new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {
                    server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8001), 0);
                    server.createContext("/ho", new MyHandler());
                    server.setExecutor(null);
                    server.start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }).execute("");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be available with JDK from 1.6 onwards. Otherwise, you can add it your build path separately. Refer below link:

You can download it from http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/sun/net/httpserver/http/20070405/http-20070405.jar

Comment: As the question does involve targeting a JVM, but rather an Android device, ordinary jar's will not work.  If the package is not included in the Android system, it would have to be re-built from source, and any missing dependencies supplied or replaced with supported alternatives.

Comment: ok i didn't know that ordinary jar will not work, but is there any way to re-built them from source to make it useful for android devices.

Comment: Hi Chris.Thanks for your answer.How can I get related source file(s) and rebuild them?