# Java and Node.js server code treated differently by firewall?

Tags: java, node.js, http, tcp, firewall

I have made 3 different types of extremely simple servers on a remote port:

1. [Java TCP Server](http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/)
2. [Java HTTP Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732109/simple-http-server-in-java-using-only-java-se-api)
3. [Node.js Server](http://howtonode.org/hello-node/hello-http.js)

I tested each separately, connecting them to the same port (call this port 9005).  They only used the code linked above, modifying ports where necessary.  When I connect to my remote server using my laptop (terminal and/or browser), 1 and 2 work, yet 3 does not.

Since 1 and 2 work, I thought there would not be any firewall issues, but could there still be some?  Since - for instance - 1 and 2 are Java but Node.js is Javascript.

Comment: It does not matter to the firewall what technology or language is used to implement a web server.  For the firewall, it matters what port, protocol and where the request is coming from.  Your question still doesn't state that all three are on the same port, but if that's the case and you're using exactly the same URLs to access all three and you're accessing them all from exactly the same computer, then the only variable left is that your server isn't actually running correctly.

Comment: I agree with jfriend00. To test either 1 use a browser on the host computer to visit the site; or 2 turn off the firewall. Either way i suspect you will find that the node.js server does not work.

Comment: So I found that basically something is wrong with my server.  Connections are made successfully when the program is installed on the Desktop but not on a folder like `C:\server`.  Weird...