# JavaScript UI With Java Base

Tags: java, javascript, user-interface

I'm working on an application written in Java, which is my main programming language. However, the GUI's Java provides are not exactly fitting for my needs. I've been struggling to create something good but kept starting over, until an Idea visited my head. 
You may have heard of Brackets, an open source project by Adobe which is a desktop application for editing HTML / CSS / JavaScript / etc. It is written in JavaScript, which makes me think that its makes a GUI using HTML and CSS. That seems like a very attractive alternative, but I do not want to have to code the entire application in Javascript.
TL;DR - I want to make a GUI in JavaScript / HTML but have the main application run on Java.

P.S. This is my first question, please be forgiving.

Comment: You can package the software with a cut down webkit browser, make your java program listen on a loopback port and dispatch html to the 'front end' browser. The hardest part in all that IMO is finding a suitable cut down web browser

Comment: @ThorSummoner: Why limit it like that? Just make the Java application serve HTTP. Then the user can use any browser they want. Example: [Plex Media Manager](https://plex.tv/)'s admin interface.

Comment: Here's a page on [Java HTTP Serving](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732109/simple-http-server-in-java-using-only-java-se-api), most OS's should support a shell open for a url; such that you launch the system default browser to open your app's url, probably in the form of `open http://localhost:80123/index.htm`

Comment: The thing is, the application shouldn't be in-browser - take a look at [Brackets](http://brackets.io/). That's more of what I want.