# Start java com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer listener in current thread, connections then should have one thread each

Tags: java, multithreading, httpserver

I am trying to make a simple HTTP server that streams data to users. I would like the server listener to block main threads execution (take over the main thread):

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws Throwable {
    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(80), 0);
    // The handler for connections
    server.createContext("/test", new MyHandler());
    // This is probably what needs tweaking
    server.setExecutor(null);
    // The start should block
    System.out.println("Server started at 0.0.0.0:80.");
    server.start();
    System.out.println("Server terminated without errors.");
}
```

The each connection will receive endless stream of data, so they need to be started in separate threads once they connect to the listening socket.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do this other than curiosity?

There are many well-tested Java HTTP servers out there, that do all that already.

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer I am writing a hackish plug-in therefore I'm trying to avoid additional worry of including other people's code while I have enough trouble including my *own code* in the running program. So no, there's no other reason than curiosity. But you have never ended up at unanswered/locked question that you really needed solution for but that was deemed useless at the time of asking?

Comment: I assume `HttpServer.create(...)` is from the Oracle JDK?
Here's a longer treatment about this and alternatives.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732109/simple-http-server-in-java-using-only-java-se-api

Answer (score 0):

If you use the internal HttpServer package from `com.sun.net.httpserver`, you can set an `java.util.concurrent.Executor` to determine how threads are being used for `MyHandler`

Comment: And how do I learn how to do that? Is there a specific executor in JDK for it? Or do I have to define such executor?

Comment: Check the docs of `java.util.concurrent.Executor`.
If you don't set it, a default implementation will be used.

Comment: Since the HttpServer you want to use is using blocking I/O, you can assume that `MyHandler` will be called in a thread per client connection.