# Running Resteasy in java se

Tags: java, resteasy

Is it possible to run resteasy or any jax-rs implementation in java se. Without the use of servlets container or javaee application container

Comment: Search for the rest easy documentation and look at the chapter embedded servers. You will see some examples

Answer (score 0):

Since Java SE 6, there's a builtin HTTP server in Sun Oracle JRE. The `com.sun.net.httpserver` package summary outlines the involved classes and contains examples. In theory that one could be used to run resteasy i guess.

**Note:** this is only available in the JVM as provided by Oracle!

The following answer [simple-http-server-in-java-using-only-java-se-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732109/simple-http-server-in-java-using-only-java-se-api) provides more details regarding providing a servlet with plain java se.