# Ant issue while running native http Server

Tags: java, ant

I need a lightweight server just for testing purpose, after some googling I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3732328/867461) answer, although my file compiles without any issue but while running I am getting the following trace back:

```
 [java] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpHandler
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:194)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.run(Java.java:771)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:221)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:135)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:108)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpHandler
 [java]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 [java]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:135)
 [java]     ... 21 more
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1374)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1323)
 [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1082)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 [java]     ... 24 more
 [java] Java Result: -1
```

**Source file**

```
package web.src.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class Server {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
    server.createContext("/test", new QuoteHandler());
    server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
    server.start();
  }

  static class QuoteHandler implements HttpHandler {
    public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
      String response = "Bazingaaaa";
      t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
      OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
      os.write(response.getBytes());
      os.close();
    }
  }
}
```

**Ant build rule**

```
  <path id="classpath.server">
    <pathelement location="lib/http-20070405.jar" />
  </path>


  <target name="server">
    <mkdir dir="${delivery.build.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${delivery.src.dir}" destdir="${delivery.build.dir}" includeantruntime="false">
      <classpath refid="classpath.server"/>
    </javac>
  </target>

  <target name="runserver">
    <java classname="web.src.example.Server">
      <classpath>
        <path refid="classpath.server" />
        <pathelement location="build/delivery"/>
      </classpath>
    </java>
  </target>
```

**Update:**

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_40-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-internal-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b13, mixed mode)
```

**Update 2**

There was some issue in jar after updating jar file I am not getting following error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/sun/net/httpserver/spi/HttpServerProvider$1, method: run signature: ()Ljava/lang/Object;) Incompatible argument to function
```

Comment: What version of Java are you running?

Comment: @rmlan updated question with java version.

Comment: Add this target and launch it <target name="print-version"> 
   <echo>Java/JVM version: ${ant.java.version}</echo> 
   <echo>Java/JVM detail version: ${java.version}</echo> 
</target>

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using the sources jar, instead of the jar that contains the compiled classes:

```
  <path id="classpath.server">
    <pathelement location="lib/http-20070405-sources.jar" />
  </path>
```

I suggest downloading the correct jar from [Maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.sun.net.httpserver%22):

- http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/sun/net/httpserver/http/20070405/http-20070405.jar

Comment: I fixed it, see my second update. After fixing it I am getting verify error.