# Is there a simple way to start a local web server using Java?

Tags: java, http, localhost, webserver

Is there a 1liner to start a local http server in java?

With Ruby: `ruby -run -e httpd -- . -p 8000`
With Python: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 4000`

When I searched on Java I found nothing so easy and a lot of confusing results, nothing close to the brief 1 liners above.

Comment: Take a look at [Spring Boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/).

Comment: Spring Boot might be a bit heavy for this if you don't intend to take advantage of any other features. Maybe some worthwhile reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732109/simple-http-server-in-java-using-only-java-se-api