# How can I test async callbacks in JMeter?

Tags: java, asynchronous, jmeter, webhooks, api-design

I am using WebHooks in my API. So, once a request is processed our REST Service will POST a response back to the callback URL sent in the request.

```
Client             Server
  |(request)         |
  |----------------->|     
  |<-----------------|     ||
  |        (response)|     ||
  |                  |    _||_ Time
  |        (callback)|    \  /
  |<-----------------|     \/
  |----------------->|
  |(response)        |
  |                  |
```

How can this be stress tested with JMeter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on WebHook implementation, if it is a matter of polling - you can just use [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) to wait for callback in loops. The whole duration of the sequence can be measured using i.e. [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller)

If the callback comes a a [Server-Sent Event](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp) you can use i.e. [JAX RS API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services) which provides [SseEventSource](https://github.com/jax-rs/api/blob/master/jaxrs-api/src/main/java/javax/ws/rs/sse/SseEventSource.java) class which can be used for waiting for server-side events either in [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) or in [Java Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) sampler like described in [Stress/Load-Testing of Asynchronous HTTP/REST Services with JMeter](http://www.codeaffine.com/2011/11/28/stressload-testing-of-asynchronous-httprest-services-with-jmeter/) article

Answer (score 2):

You have to listen to incomming connections of certain port. Make sure you machine can be connected from outside. In JMeter you can use JSR223 Sampler and following Groovy script

```
def server = new ServerSocket(8080)
while (true) {
    server.accept { socket ->
        socket.withStreams { input, output ->
            def reader = input.newReader()
            log.info('Received request:')
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                log.info(line)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution for webhook is here (JSR223 sampler)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

/* extract Content-Length: NUMBER */
def int extractContentLength(StringBuilder sb) {
    int length = 0;
    String[] lines = sb.toString().split("\\n"); 
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        String s = lines[i];
        // check if we have next line, thus ensuring we the whole number 
        if (s.toLowerCase().startsWith("Content-Length:".toLowerCase()) && i <= lines.length - 2 ) {
            String slength = s.substring(s.indexOf(":") + 1, s.length()).trim();
            length = Integer.parseInt(slength);
            //System.out.println("Length = " + length);
            log.info("Length = " + length)
            return length;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int delay = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
log.info("Starting HTTP Server on port " + port + " and delay of " + delay);

StringBuilder outputString = new StringBuilder(1000);

ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
serverSocket.setSoTimeout(delay); // 3 minutes timeout
while (true) {

    outputString.setLength(0); // reset buff

    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); // blocking
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

    try {

        boolean isBodyRead = false;
        int dataBuffer;
        while ((dataBuffer = clientSocket.getInputStream().read()) != -1) {

            if (dataBuffer == 13) { // CR
                if (clientSocket.getInputStream().read() == 10) { // LF
                    outputString.append("\n");
                }
            } else {
                outputString.append((char) dataBuffer);
            }
            
            // do we have Content length
            int len = extractContentLength(outputString);
            if (len > 0) {
                int actualLength = len - 1; // Ker je treba odštet \r\n
                for (int i = 0; i < actualLength; i++) {
                    int body = clientSocket.getInputStream().read();
                    outputString.append((char) body);
                }
                isBodyRead = true;
                break;
            }

        } // end of reading while

        if (isBodyRead) {
            out.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            out.println("Connection: close");
            out.println(); // must have empty line for HTTP
            out.flush(); 
            out.close(); // close clients connection
        }

    } catch (IOException ioEx) {
        log.info(ioEx.getMessage());
    }

    log.info(outputString.toString());
    break; // stop server - break while true
    
} // end of outer while true

serverSocket.close();
```

Test CURL script

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Connection: close" -d '{"name": "gustinmi", "email": "gustinmi at google dot com "}' -v http://localhost:8081/
```

Java version: [Simple HTTP server in Java using only Java SE API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732109/simple-http-server-in-java-using-only-java-se-api/73721360#73721360)

Configuration for JSR223 Sampler

[image]