# JMeter sending on one port and receiving on another?

Tags: jmeter

Is it possible with JMeter to send data on let's say port 8001 and then listen for a request on port 8002? Out application does not give a response but sends the data forward to another application, we need to test the throughput latency in the application.

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48025063/how-can-i-test-async-callbacks-in-jmeter

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes [TCP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Transmission_Control_Protocol_(TCP)) protocol and derivatives

1. You can send TCP or HTTP request normally using an appropriate sampler like [TCP Request](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-tcp-protocol-services-jmeter/) or [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request). Make sure to define reasonable **timeouts** otherwise JMeter will wait for the response forever (or at least as long as underlying OS allows).

   Of course when the timeout occurs the Sampler will be marked as failed, however you can tell JMeter to consider it successful by adding a [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) as its child and ticking `Ignore Status` box
2. With regards to "listen for a request" - out of box there are no test elements which would wait for incoming connections so you can do this using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and create a minimal [TCP Server](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Echo_server#Java) listening to the incoming connections and doing what needs to be done with the incoming requests