# Java Server Side: send Http POST response - status only

Tags: java, http-post, httpresponse

Some third party is sending an Http Post request whenever something changes in their DB (e.g. when a contact has been updated, they send the contactID and 'contact_updated'). I have build a socket listener that catches those requests and is able to parse the information. However, I just can't get it to work to send back a response with the status '200 - OK'. Thus, the server on the client side keeps on trying (four times or so) to re-send the request.

Is there any, simple way to just send the response status without the need of adding external libs etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be enough to send the string `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` back in your socket-listener.
If you have troubles, you can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732109/simple-http-server-in-java-using-only-java-se-api), it shows how to use a HttpServer in Java just via plain JavaSE features.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
```

to set the status code in your response header.

---

You may also set the content type.

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
```