# Pass params to a running background java process via bash script

Tags: java, linux, bash

I have a java application using switch-case in while loop to excute command. How can i pass params to a running background java process via bash script ?, I don't want to using socket or webUI to pass data. Here is my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    boolean eof = false;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (!eof) {
        System.out.println("Enter your command!");
          String data = sc.useDelimiter("\\<end>").next();
        CommandField cmdF = gson.fromJson(data, CommandField.class);
        switch (Command.Parse(cmdF.getCommand())) {
            case LOGIN:
                result = client.isLogged();
                if (result) {
                    System.out.println("successful!");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("failed!");
                }
                break;
        }
```

}

Comment: Could you please clarify, what you mean with params and background process. Is this process already running or shall it be started with the parameters?

Comment: process already running. I have edit my question. Thanks @markusw

Comment: Where is the bash script ?

Answer (score 0):

You can only pass variables to a running process by dedicated interfaces. To my mind come the following options:

- JMX (https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/source-code-java-jmx-hello-world-application)
- HTTP (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52847756/1905015)
- Socket (https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Standard:_Socket_und_ServerSocket_(java.net))
- Write to temp file, let the process look at that file and react to changes

But the program you want to pass the parameters to **must provide an implementation of the interface**. Otherwise there is no possibility to pass something if the process has no option to receive it.